# Inno setup, Only confirmoverwrite if the file contents have changed

Tags: inno-setup

How can I make Inno Setup only confirm if a file should be overwritten when the file contents have changed? With settings files, I want to confirm overwriting the existing file on the user's system. However, if that file isn't actually different than the new file in the setup, then I don't want to bother the user!

The confirmoverwrite doesn't check if the contents are different. I can't use timestamps (due to the build system). The files are text files, and so they don't have "versions", which is how Inno setup normally does checks.

Comment: You could write `checks` that would check MD5 (checksums) of files. If new MD5 <> old MD5 then check's result is True and then the file will be overwritten. I don't know how many files you want to check/install.

Comment: Comparing MD5s is actually harder than it sounds, as there is no easy way to get the MD5 of the new file. Theoretically, you could use ExtractTemporaryFile (and then GetMD5OfFile), but you can't easily get the source-name of the current file! The "CurrentFileName" only returns the destination file, and not the source file name, which ExtractTemporaryFile wants.

Comment: The MD5 sums can be generated at setup compile time and embedded in the script.

Comment: How do you access the MD5 sums? Or do you mean that I have to manually generate the sums, store it in file, and include that file in the installer, extract it, read/parse it ...?

Comment: @user2246114: the source filename should already be known to you, unless you're using wildcards -- and if you're using wildcards then you can't be using `DestName`, so `CurrentFileName` will work.  So you can either use `ExtractTemporaryFile` to calculate the checksum at install time or precalculate them as Deanna suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can accomplish this. High-level overview:

1. In `[Files]`, use preprocessor to get hashes and timestamps for the files you are installing, and pass the filename, timestamp, and hash to a Check function
2. Add Windows API functions **FileTimeToLocalFileTime** and **FileTimeToSystemTime** and a **GetFileDateTimeString** function to `[Code]` (this is because Inno Setup currently lacks a **GetFileDateTimeString** like the preprocessor has)
3. Add a global variable in `[Code]` to cache "Keep or overwrite" prompt responses (because Check functions can be called more than once)
4. Add a Check function in `[Code]` that accepts the file path, hash, and timestamp string as parameters

### `[Files]` Section

Here's sample code for the `[Files]` section:

```
[Files]
#define FindHandle
#define FindResult
#sub ProcessFoundFile
#define FilePath "config\" + FindGetFileName(FindHandle)
#define FileHash GetSHA1OfFile(FilePath)
#define FileTime GetFileDateTimeString(FilePath, 'yyyymmddhhnnss', '', '')
#define FileName ExtractFileName(FilePath)
Source: "{#FilePath}"; DestDir: "{app}\config"; Check: ShouldCopyFile('{app}\config\{#FileName}', '{#FileHash}', '{#FileTime}')
#endsub
#for {FindHandle = FindResult = FindFirst("config\*", 0); FindResult; FindResult = FindNext(FindHandle)} ProcessFoundFile
```

In this example, we are installing files from the `config` directory. The preprocessor enumerates the files in the `config` directory and outputs a `Source:` line for each found file that contains the file's path, the SHA1 hash of the file, and a string representation of the file's timestamp.

### `[Code]` Section

Here's sample code for the `[Code]` section:

```
var
  ShouldCopy: Variant;

// Windows file and system time functions
function FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTime: TFileTime; var LocalFileTime: TFileTime): Boolean;
  external 'FileTimeToLocalFileTime@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function FileTimeToSystemTime(FileTime: TFileTime; var SystemTime: SYSTEMTIME): Boolean;
  external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  result := true;
  ShouldCopy := CreateOleObject('Scripting.Dictionary');
end;

function GetFileHash(const FileName: string): string;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    result := GetSHA1OfFile(FileName);
  finally
  end;
end;

// Return file date/time as string: 'yyyymmddhhnnss'
function GetFileDateTimeString(FileName: string): string;
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  LocalFileTime: TFileTime;
  LocalTime: SYSTEMTIME;
begin
  result := '';
  try
    if FindFirst(FileName, FindRec) then
    begin
      if FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FindRec.LastWriteTime, LocalFileTime) then
      begin
        if FileTimeToSystemTime(LocalFileTime, LocalTime) then
          result := Format('%4.4d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d%2.2d', [LocalTime.wYear,
            LocalTime.wMonth, LocalTime.wDay, LocalTime.wHour, LocalTime.wMinute,
            LocalTime.wSecond]);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FindClose(FindRec);
  end;
end;

function ShouldCopyFile(const FilePath, SourceFileHash, SourceFileTime: string): Boolean;
var
  TargetFilePath, TargetFileHash, TargetFileTime: string;
begin
  TargetFilePath := ExpandConstant(FilePath);
  // Copy if file doesn't exist
  if not FileExists(TargetFilePath) then
  begin
    result := true;
    exit;
  end;
  TargetFileHash := GetFileHash(TargetFilePath);
  if TargetFileHash = '' then
  begin
    result := true;
    exit;
  end;
  // Source and target have same hash: Don't copy
  if CompareText(SourceFileHash, GetSHA1OfFile(TargetFilePath)) = 0 then
  begin
    result := false;
    exit;
  end;
  // At this point, we know the files are different...
  TargetFileTime := GetFileDateTimeString(TargetFilePath);
  if TargetFileTime = '' then
  begin
    result := true;
    exit;
  end;
  // Source timestamp <= target: Don't copy
  if CompareText(SourceFileTime, TargetFileTime) <= 0 then
  begin
    result := false;
    exit;
  end;
  // At this point, we know source timestamp > target...
  // Use cached response if available
  if ShouldCopy.Exists(TargetFilePath) then
  begin
    result := ShouldCopy.Item(TargetFilePath);
    exit;
  end;
  // Prompt to keep or overwrite
  result := SuppressibleTaskDialogMsgBox('Keep existing file?',
    'Should Setup keep the following file?' + #10#10 + TargetFilePath,
    mbConfirmation,
    MB_YESNO, ['&Keep the existing file', '&Overwrite the existing file'],
    0,
    idYes) = IDNO;
  // Cache response
  ShouldCopy.Add(TargetFilePath, result);
end;
```

Notes on the code:

- Compares file times as strings (hence the `yyyymmddhhnnss` format)
- `Scripting.Dictionary` ActiveX (OLE) object caches Check function prompt responses
- Files on disk that are newer are skipped
- Specifying `/suppressmsgboxes` on the command line defaults to keeping existing files

This solution essentially provides a "prompt to keep or overwrite file if the existing file is different and older than the file being installed" feature. (Perhaps they will add a `promptifdifferentandolder` flag to Inno Setup in a later version...)